# Is Data order of BlockingCollection queue guaranteed when data is added by multiple threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I'm using queue implemented by BlockingCollection class to implement producer-consumer model queue.

I have multiple threads adding elements in specified order(for each of the threads only), and one thread taking elements out of it.

I don't care about ordering of elements added between different threads, but I expect elements added by each of the threads to be in the order that it has been added.

Does BlockingCollection class guarantee this? I've googled it, but couldn't find clear answer to my question.

Comment: `BlockingCollection` wraps another connection type. Are you explicitly providing one in its constructor? If so, look at it's guarantees. If not, it'll use a `ConcurrentQueue` - so look at that type's guarantees.

Comment: Yes, I provided CocurrentQueue. It should guarantee the element order if each thread since It's FIFO.. am I right?

Answer (score 2):

[`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.1), the default collection behind a `BlockingCollection<T>` states that it is a:

> thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection.

They do not feel the need to highlight any other threading concerns, either in the class documentation itself nor in the documentation for `Enqueue` and `TryDequeue`.

I'd prefer something stronger to be documented, which I think is what you're looking for, but the best I can offer is, it says it's FIFO, I have to trust that it is.